# Why this works in C# (generic class and self-reference)?

Tags: c#, class, generics, self-reference

I have

```
class X<T> : Base
{
//For exemple:
    static T something();
}
```

And I can have

```
class A : X <A> 
{
}
```

To logically have something like this:

```
class A : Base
{
    static A something();
}
```

This works and works well.

But in my comprehension, it's kind of self-reference (A is the children of X, while X doesn't exists before A...), which is breaks the foundation of computer science, so I want to know what's wrong with my comprehension??

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean it's a good idea. ;)

Comment: @SolarBear I see no bad ideas here.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you expect this not to work?  There's nothing logically incoherent about "a class with a method that returns an instance of that class."

Comment: @TimGoodman  when A doesn't exist, X<A> should not exist, because A is not there, so given X<A> doesn't exist before A, A can not inherit from X<A>

Comment: You do that many times actually, with IComparable<T> for example

Comment: @Enzojz I guess you're thinking of it as the inheritance chain looping back on itself, like A inherits from B and B inherits from A?  But it's not that, since T is a type parameter.  A inherits from X<T> with the value of T being A.  It *sounds* circular, but it's not going to throw the compiler into an infinite loop.

Comment: Ask yourself this, for instance: Did your brain go into an infinite loop trying to figure out the return type of `A.something`?  Is there any question the compiler has to answer about `A` that you can't reason out without going into an infinite loop?  The compiler is smarter than we are. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally fine. You can do similar without generics too:

```
class Test
{
    public static Test GetInstance()
    {
        return new Test();
    }
}
```

I don't see any self-reference here. And actually it's quite useful pattern e.g. when implementing singletons. Simplified concept (I know, it should use locks, etc...):

```
public static class Singleton<T> where T : new()
{
    private static T _instance;

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        return _instance ?? (_instance = new T());
    }
}
```

**Edit - Answering your comment question:**

**`X<T>` already *exists* for all suitable `T` parameters.** By suitable I mean every type that suits generic constraint (or just every type when there is no constraint). And by every I mean not only all classes available within your assembly. Just **every** suitable type.

Generic class/method is just a template which is resolved for given particular generic type **in runtime**. That's why you don't have to even use the generic class at all in assemble it's declared within. And that's why your code works fine.

Comment: This is no problem for me because the constructor of Test exists already. But for my case, when A doesn't exists, X<A> should not exists, because A is not there, so given X<A> doesn't exists before A, A can not herited from X<A>

Comment: I know singleton, I use it quite a lot.. the point is not there.